# How to add a value to array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add a new value to state array but it gives me error.

**code**

```js
async shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.navigation.state.params.updated) {
      const { updated } = prevProps.navigation.state.params;
      // updated = object
      const { typeTwo, typeThree } = this.state;
      const typeTwoUpdated = await typeTwo.filter((v) => v.id !== updated.id);
      const typeThreeUpdated = await typeThree.push(updated);
      this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwoUpdated, typeThree: typeThreeUpdated });
    }
  }
```

**Error**

```
> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: typeThree.push is not a function. (In 'typeThree.push(updated)', 'typeThree.push' is undefined)]
```

**Edit**

Changed the code.

```js
async shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.navigation.state.params.updated) {
      const { updated } = prevProps.navigation.state.params;
      // updated = object
      const { typeTwo, typeThree } = this.state;
      // typeThree = []
      const typeTwoUpdated = typeTwo.filter((v) => v.id !== updated.id);
      this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwoUpdated, typeThree: [...typeThree, updated] });
    }
  }
```

**new error**

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.]

Comment: Could you please show an example of what the typeThree object/array is?

Comment: typeThree is a array

Comment: Sounds like you do no have an array

Comment: It says right in the error, you aren't handling the promise's sucess or fail option before using it.

Comment: That's my concern... they are set equal to a state object through a deconstruction method and I don't know what that makes each type. It cannot be an array, it must be an object or undefined. If it's undefined - initialize it without deconstruction.

Comment: maybe `typeThree` is not an array , it can be an object

Comment: This is almost certainly an incomplete example. Either you’re `await`ing the response from a synchronous native method or `typeThree` is not an array. The native method returns the new length, but you’re expecting a modified array as the return value, and your error suggests `push` isn’t defined on the target caller. In short, we need more details.

Comment: Why are you using `await` with `filter` and `push`? If they are normal array methods, they are not asynchronous.

Comment: DO NOT MUTATE STATE DIRECTLY!

Comment: Also, .push is a normal method, and it even doesn't return updated array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check initial state, particularly state.typeThree.
The `shouldComponentUpdate` could be run before you call this.setState({typeThree: Array})

Edit: Please do not add items to an array that is referenced in React component state.
`const typeThreeUpdated = typeThree && typeThree.length ? [...typeThree] : [];`

`typeThreeUpdated.push(updated);`

`this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwoUpdated, typeThree: typeThreeUpdated });`

Edit 2: So here is what happens

`const typeThreeUpdated = await typeThree.push(updated);`

this line will result in typeThreeUpdated to be an integer value, which is the new length of typeThree after pushing a new element. The `push` mutates the array but returns not the new array, instead it returns the new length.  Then it's stored in state as `typeThree` in  this line

`this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwoUpdated, typeThree: typeThreeUpdated });`

and in the next time the function runs, this.state.typeThree is still that number, which has no push function.

Note that you don't need `await` here

Comment: ```typeThree: []``` in initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.navigation.state.params.updated) {
      const { updated } = prevProps.navigation.state.params;
      // updated = object
      const { typeTwo, typeThree } = this.state;
      // typeThree = []
      const typeTwoUpdated = typeTwo.filter((v) => v.id !== updated.id);
      this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwoUpdated, typeThree: [...typeThree, updated });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

First of all, `Array.prototype.push` is a synchronous operation, it does not need await.

Secondly, it returns the `length` of the array when called and mutates the underlying array.

Example

```js
const animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

const count = animals.push('cows');
console.log(count);
// expected output: 4
console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows"]
```

You have two ways of doing it:

### Mutating

```js
      typeThree.push(updated);
      this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwo.filter((v) => v.id !== updated.id), typeThree });
```

### Immutable (The right way)

```js
      this.setState({ typeTwo: typeTwo.filter((v) => v.id !== updated.id), typeThree: [...typeThree, updated] });
```

Comment: Accept this answer if it helped you